# Change string value of an array to another string value

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have something like this:

```
Collection {#296 ▼
#items: array:1318 [▼
0 => {#289 ▼
  +"Column1": "string1"
  +"Column2": "string2"
  +"Column3": "string3"
  +"Column4": "string4"
  +"Column5": "string5"
 }
1 => {#292 ▼
  +"Column1": "string6"
  +"Column2": "string7"
  +"Column3": "string8"
  +"Column4": "string9"
  +"Column5": "string10"
 }
2 => {#293 ▼
  +"Column1": "string11"
  +"Column2": "string12"
  +"Column3": "string13"
  +"Column4": "string14"
  +"Column5": "string15"
 }
]
}
```

For each "Column1" I need to change the string value to another.
Can you help me?
Regards

I'll explain better now:

if Column1 is equal to a certain value, then Column2 is equal to my string

I have tried this:

```
 foreach($all as $key=>$row){
        if($row->Column1 = 'NUMAX'){
            $ipoltstatus = Str::before($row->message, '_');
            $olthostname = Olt::where('ipaddress', $ipoltstatus)->value('hostname');

            $row->Column2 = $olthostname;

        }
```

what happens is that all Column1 columns mistakenly take the NUMAX value and column2 becomes empty

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Modify collection data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39751739/laravel-modify-collection-data)

Comment: Can you provide an example of input and expected output?

Comment: type mistake `if($row->Column1 = 'NUMAX'){` to `if($row->Column1 == 'NUMAX'){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP comparison is done by `===` not `=`, a single equal sign is for setting a value. So changing `=` to `===` should do the trick. Also there is `==` and `===`, two equal signs type juggles and triple compares the variables as is. `2 == '2'` is true and `2 === '2'` is false.

```
foreach ($all as $key => $row) {
    if ($row->Column1 === 'NUMAX') {
```